# Android Button or any other view not clickable

Tags: android, button, click

I have set this flag

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```

for creating lock screen and got the success but not able to getting click listen event for buttons which I have display on screen.

My code as below

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lockscreen);
findViewById(R.id.btnClear).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```